# Trying to figure out how to build a query in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am having some trouble building the query I need to return the AccountID from the FamilyAccountDetails table where the Family account has at least one child(a child is where the AccountDetails.AccountID equals the FamilyAccountDetails.AccountID) that has a HoldFlag = 0.

```
AccountDetails
EntID  |HoldFlag|AccountID|StatusFlag

FamilyAccountDetails
EntID|FamilyAccountID|AccountID|StatusFlag
```

SQL:

```
      Select FD.AccountID, FD.FamilyAccountId 
from Test2TMAdvisor5.dbo.FamilyAccountDetails FD
      where FD.EnterpriseId = 'TestDan'
      and AccountId in (Select AccountId from Test2TMAdvisor5.dbo.AccountDetails AD where Ad.AccountID = FD.AccountId and ad.HoldFlag =0)
```

Comment: Did you check this **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11255337/1451723)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    FD.[AccountID]
    ,FD.[FamilyAccountId] 
FROM
    FamilyAccountDetails FD
WHERE
    FD.[EnterpriseId] = 'TestDan'
    AND EXISTS 
        (
        SELECT 
            * 
        FROM 
            AccountDetails AD
        WHERE 
            AD.[AccountID] = FD.[AccountId] 
            AND AD.[HoldFlag] = 0
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

This SQL query should extract the results you want:

```
SELECT
    FD.[AccountID]
    ,FD.[FamilyAccountId] 
FROM
    FamilyAccountDetails FD
INNER JOIN AccountDetails AD on AD.[AccountID] = FD.[AccountId] 
WHERE
    FD.EntID = 'TestDan'
    AND AD.[HoldFlag] = 0
```